# Why are different sized images loaded as the same size in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am currently loading a lot of different sized images in numpy, but seem to have some problems regarding the the shape of the matrices.  They are all the same, eventhough the images are different.

Example:

[image: long rectangular image]

[image: square image]

Both are loaded using this function.

```
def load_image( infilename ) :
    img = Image.open( infilename )
    img.load()
    data = np.asarray( img, dtype="int32" )
    return data
```

but both have `data.shape` is (441,816,3)
  441 makes sense, since all the images has the same number of rows, and 3 since it is RGB, but 816 makes no sense?.. they have different number of columns? ... So why is it loaded as if all of them had same number of columns.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you're passing the wrong thing for `infilename` and it doesn't change from call to call. Try adding an `img.show()` into the code temporarily to see what was loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is not in the code you show. I've tried with your images and the following program:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

def load_image(infilename):
    img = Image.open(infilename)
    img.load()
    data = np.asarray(img, dtype="int32")
    return data

one = load_image("one.png")
two = load_image("two.png")

print "One:", one.shape
print "Two:", two.shape
```

The output was

```
One: (441, 1302, 3)
Two: (441, 543, 3)
```

Comment: you are absolute right.. Nothing is wrong with the code. It was just the way i used it!